# Java ActionListener displaying false output

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have a problem with my ActionListener in Java (Eclipse).
The programm is supposed to ask you question about diverse topics in maths. Here is the part of the code, which includes the problem:

```
public Frame () {
    c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("Test");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);        
    addition = new JMenuItem("Addition");
    addition.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    menu.add(addition);     
    minus = new JMenuItem("Subtraction");
    minus.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    menu.add(minus);        
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    menuBar.add(menu);

    answer = new JButton("Answer");
    c.add(answer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    next = new JButton("Next");
    c.add(next, BorderLayout.EAST);

    back = new JButton("Back");
    c.add(back, BorderLayout.WEST);

    beschriftung = new JLabel();
    beschriftung.setText("Welcome! Please choose your desired operation at the top.");
    beschriftung.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    beschriftung.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    c.add(beschriftung,BorderLayout.CENTER);    

    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            i = 1+dice.nextInt(99);
            j = 1+dice.nextInt(99);
            k = i + j;
            beschriftung.setText("Next Question: " + i + "+" + j);
        }
    });


addition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        beschriftung.setText("Addition Questions!");    
        c.remove(nextminus);
        next = new JButton("Next");
        c.add(next, BorderLayout.EAST); 

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b) {
                i = 1+dice.nextInt(99);
                j = 1+dice.nextInt(99);
                k = i + j;
                beschriftung.setText("Next Question: " + i + "+" + j);

            }
        });

        answer2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {
                beschriftung.setText(i + "+" + j + "= " + k);
            }
        });

    }
});

minus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        beschriftung.setText("Subtraction Questions!"); 
        c.remove(next);
        nextminus = new JButton("Next!");
        c.add(nextminus, BorderLayout.EAST);

        nextminus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {
                i = 1+dice.nextInt(99);
                j = 1+dice.nextInt(99);
                k = i - j;
                beschriftung.setText("Next Question: " + i + "-" + j);
            }
        });

        answer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {
                beschriftung.setText(i + "-" + j + "= " + k);
             }
        });
    }
});

}
```

It doesnt output anything when I click on JButton "answer" while in the addition tab.

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the action listener to the wrong button. Try using `answer.addActionListener()` instead of `answer2.addActionListener()` in the action listener for the addition menu bar item.